# Как найти картинку сохраненную ( jpeg) на рабочем столе?

Tags: java

Суть такая я открыл сохранил картинку, далее ее открыл в jpeg и джава должна найти область на всем рабочем экране и щелкнуть мышкой (левой или правой) ну или сообщение вывести что изображение найдено 1 раз или не найдено

Comment: За вас никто этого делать не будет. Прикрепляйте код, где вы пытались это сделать.

Comment: Можно сходу избежать кучу проблем, если использовать какой-нибудь формат сжатия без потерь. JPEG к ним не относится.

Answer (score -2):

поиск изображения в изображении. Есть два изображения: большое, и маленькое. На большом надо найти маленькое. Например: чтоб на робочем столе программа знала место расположения папок? Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Вот код

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Motor {

```
    int[] findSubimage(BufferedImage im1, BufferedImage im2){
           int w1 = im1.getWidth(); int h1 = im1.getHeight();
           int w2 = im2.getWidth(); int h2 = im2.getHeight();
           assert(w2 <= w1 && h2 <= h1);
           // will keep track of best position found
           int bestX = 0; int bestY = 0; double lowestDiff = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
           // brute-force search through whole image (slow...)
           for(int x = 0;x < w1-w2;x++){
             for(int y = 0;y < h1-h2;y++){
               double comp = compareImages(im1.getSubimage(x,y,w2,h2),im2);
               if(comp < lowestDiff){
                 bestX = x; bestY = y; lowestDiff = comp;
               }
             }
           }
           // output similarity measure from 0 to 1, with 0 being identical
           System.out.println(lowestDiff);
           System.out.println(bestX+" "+bestY);
           // return best location
           return new int[]{bestX,bestY};

         }



/**
 * Determines how different two identically sized regions are.
 */
private double compareImages(BufferedImage im1, BufferedImage im2) {
    assert(im1.getHeight() == im2.getHeight() && im1.getWidth() == im2.getWidth());
   double variation = 0.0;
   for(int x = 0;x < im1.getWidth();x++){
     for(int y = 0;y < im1.getHeight();y++){
        variation += compareARGB(im1.getRGB(x,y),im2.getRGB(x,y))/Math.sqrt(3);
     }
   }
   return variation/(im1.getWidth()*im1.getHeight());

}
/**
 * Calculates the difference between two ARGB colours (BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB).
 */
private double compareARGB(int rgb1, int rgb2) {
    double r1 = ((rgb1 >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0; double r2 = ((rgb2 >> 16) & 0xFF)/255.0;
   double g1 = ((rgb1 >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0;  double g2 = ((rgb2 >> 8) & 0xFF)/255.0;
   double b1 = (rgb1 & 0xFF)/255.0;         double b2 = (rgb2 & 0xFF)/255.0;
   double a1 = ((rgb1 >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0; double a2 = ((rgb2 >> 24) & 0xFF)/255.0;
   // if there is transparency, the alpha values will make difference smaller
   return a1*a2*Math.sqrt((r1-r2)*(r1-r2) + (g1-g2)*(g1-g2) + (b1-b2)*(b1-b2));
}
```

}

p.s. Как заставить его работать? где порписать путь к файлу ( картинке в jpg ) ? как сделать GUI тупо  2 кнопки нажал, загрузил файл, нажал он нашел картинку выдал сообщение нашел или не нашел.

p.s.s. Сорри, на джаве всего 2 мес. программлю......